# How do I solve $\int\frac{dy}{2y+y^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

the integral is:

$$\int\frac{dy}{2y+y^2}$$

So I had:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{dy}{y(y-1)} = \frac{A}{y} + \frac{B}{y-1}$$

so $$\begin{cases}A=-1 \\ B=1 \end{cases}$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(-\int\frac{dy}{y}+\int\frac{dy}{y-2}\right)$$

and the end $$\frac{1}{2}\left(-\ln|y|+\ln|y-2|\right) + C$$

But original answer is:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln|x-2|-\ln|x|\right)+C$$

What did I miss?

Comment: You put y in place of  x and didn't order them like in the book :)

Comment: Your answer is also right.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense at all. How did you get from $\int\frac{dy}{2y+y^2}$ to $\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{dy}{y(y-1)}$? How did you end up with $y-2$ again after factoring into $y-1$? Why is the book's answer in terms of $x$ instead of $y$?

Comment: @Wyllich In what way is the answer right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hate partial fraction decomposition, you could also try completing the square in the denominator. Doing this yields

\begin{align*} 
\int \frac{1}{y^2+2y} dx = \int \frac{1}{(y+1)^2 - 1 } dx
\end{align*}

Now make the substitution that $\sec(\theta) = y + 1 \ \Rightarrow\ dy = \sec\theta\tan{\theta}d\theta$. Therefore,

\begin{align*}
\int \frac{1}{(y+1)^2 - 1 } dx & = \int \frac{\sec\theta\tan\theta}{\sec^{2}\theta - 1} d\theta\\
&=\int \frac{\sec\theta\tan\theta}{\tan^2\theta} d\theta\\
&= \int \csc(\theta) d\theta\\
&= -\ln|\csc\theta + \cot\theta| + C.
\end{align*}

Now make the usual backward trig subs for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This

$\int\frac{dy}{y(y+2)} = \frac{A}{y} + \frac{B}{y+2}$

\begin{cases}
Ay+By=0 \iff A=-B\\
2A=1 \iff A= \frac 1 2
\end{cases}

Then (A,B)=(1/2,-1/2)

The solution is $g(y)= -\frac {1} 2\ln \mid (y+2) \mid+ \frac 1 2 \ln\mid y\mid + K$